# Does clipboard change character encoding?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, clipboard, character-encoding

I am having a UTF8-related issue in a piece of software - it complains some text containing special characters isn't valid UTF8. But whenever I copy-paste it into an online validation tool or into an email on a user-group, it reports as valid UTF8.

The suspicion is it might be in some older pre UTF8 format but I wonder, as soon as it goes into the clipboard, or get's pasted into my browser, will it be converted to UTF8? That's the first question.

The 'offending' text is presented in an HTTP webpage, so secondly, how can I definitively see what is being served up, how exactly the special characters are represented?

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard holds a copy and then at a later time pastes it into the receiving app.

Clipboard does not change character encoding or other attributes on the way by.

Old special characters might cause problems either source or receiving app, so you should update these characters.

Answer (score 0):

The clipboard API in Windows is capable of converting between many formats,
but not all formats.

To find out what is actually put on the clipboard, and excellent tool is
[Free Clipboard Viewer](https://freeclipboardviewer.com/),
which can help in analyzing where is the problem.

If this doesn't solve the puzzle, please give directions as to how I may duplicate
the copy. As another test, you may also copy text that is clearly UTF-8,
for example from Notepad++ where the encoding is set to UTF-8, and test it
in this program (which is which?).